# PNG ImageData to Bitmap in android

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have a string say,

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

How can I get to Bitmap from this data?

Comment: strip off data uri, base64 decode. take raw string as png image, convert to bmp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506428/convert-base64-string-to-image-in-java

Comment: @MarcB, seems very easy. Can you write two lines of code for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First get the string after comma, then do this:

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```