# How to get BLOB image file from MYSQL server via JSON efficiently

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, image

My MYSQL db contains 5 rows

```
id, name, username, password, email, image
```

The image type is BLOB.

My PHP codes below to get JSON data from MYSQL.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
     array_push($result,
         array('id'=>$row[0],
               'name'=>$row[1],
               'username'=>$row[2],
               'password'=>$row[3],
               'email'=>$row[4],
               'image'=>$row[5])
               ));
}

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
```

My application will load longer than expected to parse the base64 image string from the returned JSON.

So what's the best way to store and retrieve image file efficiently?

Comment: one suggestion is to store `imagepath` and not image in your `db` , and show images in android from that `imagepath` you received via `json`

Comment: The simple answer is it's completely inefficient. and the only way to make it efficient is not to store images as blobs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem. So I avoided storing images in MySql.
I am storing them in the server as image files and using picasso to show the images. Its super easy to transform and use.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Above code is correct and you are getting `base64` as image you can simply do this

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
     array_push($result,
         array('id'=>$row[0],
               'name'=>$row[1],
               'username'=>$row[2],
               'password'=>$row[3],
               'email'=>$row[4],
               'image'=>$row[5])
               ));
}

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
```

on Android side you can do some thing like this to convert it to image.

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

[Convert base64 string to Image in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506428/convert-base64-string-to-image-in-java) taken as reference

Comment: I've tried this, I got a `textview` to display JSON data, it show null when use this method

Comment: @cwfei : originally you were using reference to the image like `&row[5]` and not to value itself i.e `$row[5]` try this approach again

Comment: That's my mistake but I've correct it, without `base64_decode` i get something like `"image":"\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRASJDASDJA\/........"`, a very long string

Comment: thats the actual `base 64` converted image all you need to do is send the data as it is to client i.e android device and decode it on client end.

Comment: @cwfei: All you have to do is send the base64 string to client i.e android and decode it there, i have shared a sample on how to do it, there are other few ways to do that too.

Comment: Thanks for your edited answer, I've tried this before and it works, but will it be lag if obtain multiple images base64 string at once?

Comment: Well yes, but depends how you render them, e.g if you are loading 10 images or 20 , it wont be much of a problem, but if it is a huge number it will be lagy, to avoid this, you can call data in a `paginated` way. Even with async calls we cannot guarantee if the images are small or large. Loading images with URL in android still can be laggy. So its best if you have a strategy about loading images. I personally load images in a paginated way, e.g ask server to send me 10 items on activity swipe down etc